# How to open a file in a specific editor group in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to open a file in VSCode from the terminal in a specific editor group. I am able to open a file in the *active* editor group using the command

```
code <file_name>
```

In the **Explorer** tab, the **Open Editors** section displays files group-wise. I have 3 groups and it shows like this

```
GROUP 1
    <file1>
GROUP 2
    <file2>
GROUP 3
    <file3>
```

Is there any way I could mention the group number of the group in which I want to open the file in the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way.

Neither the `code` nor `code-insider` command lines does support such scenario so, you are out of luck.

If you really need such option, I would suggest you to open a feature request in VS Code repo (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md), so the team could evaluate.

On the other hand, I think it would be doable via Extension, if the extension itself also provides support to open external resources, which could combine with a new CLI to *talk* to it. Just an idea.

Hope this helps